# Diffusion in a Sphere - Average concentration considering initial and final concentration

Tags: diffusion

I am looking a diffusion in sphere, but I am afraid that, as a chemist, my limited understanding of mathematics and differential equation is hindering me, but I am hoping that perhaps some of you can point me in the right direction.
In specific, I am trying to work out a function for total concentration of a diffusing species in a sphere as a function of time, diffusion coefficient and radius for different non-zero initial concentrations, and also the rate of this mass/concentration change.

I am using equations from a textbook Mathematics of Diffusion by Crank ([https://www-eng.lbl.gov/~shuman/NEXT/MATERIALS&COMPONENTS/Xe_damage/Crank-The-Mathematics-of-Diffusion.pdf](https://www-eng.lbl.gov/%7Eshuman/NEXT/MATERIALS&COMPONENTS/Xe_damage/Crank-The-Mathematics-of-Diffusion.pdf))

After taking Ficks second law in radial coordinates and with some boundary conditions, they give the relative concentration in equation 6.18:

[image]

with a the total radius, r, the radial position, D, the diffusion coefficient and t, time.
Integrating over the volume gives:

[image]

Now this equation is ideal for the case where the initial concentration is 0. The rate of change at t = 0 is also infinity, since the concentration gradient is infinite. My problem is that I want to start from a non-zero concentration and I cannot work it out. Its clear that I cannot simply change C1 and integrate. I think it has to do with some boundary conditions that are not mentioned in the textbook. Do I need to work with partial differential equations?
I would be very grateful if you could point me in some directions to solve this!

Cheers!